# My function does not split the decimal number to two parts, instead it prints ERROR

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def Answer():
     A = var1.get()
     if "." not in A and A.isdigit():
         Right1.insert(END,str(A)+"est un entier")

     elif "." in A  and A.isdigit():

          B,C = A.split(".")
          Right1.insert(END,str(B)+"est decimal" + str(C)+"est entier")
    else :
         Right1.insert(END,"ERROR")
```

That is my function Answer for my thinker. When I enter an `Interger(12)`, I see the "`Integer(12) est un entier`".
But when I enter a decimal number (`12.7`), it prints: `ERROR` instead of splitting the number to two part. I should have on my screen: "`12 est decimal`"   "`7 est entier`". Any ideas where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `.` is not a digit...

Comment: I am trying to split in two parts a decimal numbers. So I have to check if the number has a point, if it does , I devise the number then. I am not checking if . is a digit.

Comment: You are checking if `.` is a digit in your code, but you shouldn't be. Check my answer for a more pythonic solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should check to see what type the values are before taking an action. `12` is an `int` and `12.7` is a `float`.

So using that information we can do the below:

```
a = [12, 12.7]

for i in a:
    if type(i) == int:
        print(str(i)+" est un entier.")
    elif type(i) == float:
        print(str(i).split(".")[0]+" est decimal "+str(i).split(".")[1]+" est entier.")
```

Comment: Thank you!  I understand better now.

Comment: Maybe use PEP8 for indention.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Yeah my Python started indenting differently today. I must have pressed something, need to change it.

Comment: @edmundo If this answers your question, please can you mark it as accepted so that other users can learn from this.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Fixed